# Asp.net How to update sql table column if unexpectedly PC was shutdown

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

**Scenario:** I am working on website in which user login and do some tasks and logout. When user login in website I put a true value in database so other user is not logged in with the same username and password.

**Problem:** Above scenario was working fine. But I a face problem when unexpectedly PC was shutdown and that true value is there which I put in database on the first time when user login in my website. And the first user is unable to again logged in from same PC.

**What I want:** I need a mechanism in asp.net in which When unexpectedly PC was restarted / shutdown server automatically update my column in sql.

Comment: Sounds like a bad design. Based on what it seems you are trying to enforce, logging in again should invalidate the other session, so you need to give a user a new session and make sure the old sessions for the same user is deleted and no longer allows them to use the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use server code to monitor client machine behavior.
I suggest you re-design the database with a expiring time session, which will handle the login event when "true" value is on but user try to login again.

Another the way could be allowing users to "unlock" themselves, by email-reset token, or by secret password.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a mechanism in asp.net in which When unexpectedly PC was restarted / shutdown server automatically update my column in sql.

SignalR can help. On your website you have a HUB, that hub can detect when users connect or disconnect. Just map when disconnect is called and set that user in the database to false.

I agree with previous comments that it's a poor design. But SignalR can work around that for you.

http://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: SignR is good, but SignR itself won't solve the underlying problem of same username accessing from different browser or machine.

Comment: Actually it would solve it. SingalR you have access to all connections connected. You can manually disconnect users or run a logout routine if need be.

Comment: I agree that SignalR is one good option. However, my point is without redesigning the database OP won't be able to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't understand why OP would need to redesign the database. OP asked for a mechanism to update the database when the client disconnects unexpectedly. SingalR Hub can detect if a client disconnects gracefully or timeout. Therefor if the client disconnects then update the database with the false value. EDIT: I agree the time to implement SignalR would most likely be greater than swapping to a cookie based system like you proposed. But OP asked for a mechanism to implement.

Comment: You are missing the main point in the question - OP is trying to implement **sign-out everywhere** - basically if a user sign-in from a browser, the system should automatically sign-out from other browsers.

Comment: No I get the point. Which is why I suggested SignalR. All other connections (relating the the username or not) can be forced to logout. I'm not saying its most elegant system. In my post I agree OP has a poor design. I still don't see where redesigning the database comes into it.

Answer (score 0):

> When user login in website I put a true value in database so other
>   user is not logged in with the same username and password.

It is not a good design, because internet is not reliable. You are very closed; instead of Boolean value in database, you want to store a token.

### Solution

You need to redesign the system based on cookie *(or you can also use bearer token)*.

When a user login, create a new token and store it in both database  and cookie.

When a user request a page, validate submitted cookie with the one in database. If they are not same, ask the user to re-login again.